# How to manage react-native codepush versions?

Tags: javascript, react-native, versioning, code-push, react-native-code-push

I'm going to apply codepush to react-native.

The app is currently distributed to the store.
I haven't applied codepush yet.

But I have a question.

For example, suppose the version of the app deployed in the store is v1.0.0.
And we applied codepush (staging, production) to distribute version v1.0.1 to the store.

Also, we needed a simple code modification, not a native code, so we distributed it to the codepush production environment instead of the store.

1. In this case, how should I manage the version? Do I change it to v1.0.2?
2. In the above case, the problem is that the store version is v1.0.1 and the codepush version is v1.0.2. Users with codepush will receive a bundler update that corresponds to v1.0.2, but users with versions earlier than v1.0.1 will not be able to receive the update.
3. Then, is it good to distribute codepush and distribute it to the store as well?

I didn't have this concern when I used codepush for internal testing, but I'm trying to apply it to the app distributed in the store, so I don't know what to do about version control.

Is there anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is over a year old but I came across it and can share what we do at my company in case anyone else is wondering. We only increase the version if we are submitting a new binary to the App Store. Usually that will mean there are native changes involved. If we are just pushing javascript changes (for a quick bug fix for example), we use CodePush and we don't increase the version. Hope that provides some guidance!